# error inflating ConstraintLayout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm having problems with Android Studio. I recently upgraded my SDK Manager to include;

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
```

classpath is

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Project builds fine. Intellisense and documentation works fine. But when I try to run (in debug) the app on my phone I get this error;

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:
 Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class ConstraintLayout
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:443)
                   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
```

I've synced gradle. I've restarted Android Studio. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
thanks!

-edit-
XML looks like this;

```
<ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/PLAY_PARENT"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/greenfelt2"
android:padding="0dp">
```

Comment: add your xml code.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should add as below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/PLAY_PARENT"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/greenfelt2"
 android:padding="0dp">
```

`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

For the latest release check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project)

check out this project for more on [ConstraintLayout Usage](https://github.com/Arjun-sna/android-constraintlayout-demo)

**Update**

For those who are switching from android support to `androidx`, remember to change `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Doing so results in this error; "using version 1.0.0-beta5, this version of the constraint library is obsolete. It's just a damn intellisense error. It still builds and runs... (I didn't even try running once I saw that error...). Thanks.

Comment: check out this project for more on ConstraintLayout https://github.com/Arjun-sna/android-constraintlayout-demo

Comment: If you have warnings, use current version: 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Comment: just an update. New version of the constraint layout is been out. `1.1.0`

Comment: For those who are switching from android support to androidx, remember to change `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this was solution 2 and half years ago, but today i had similar error. Found the answer right here: [Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout after migration to androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882606/error-inflating-class-androidx-constraintlayout-constraintlayout-after-migration/52882787)

Basically only xml tags of constraint layout should be renamed to these ->

**androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**

Answer (score 4):

If You using androidx, you must use

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be number of reasons

1. dependency version issue (same like above)
2. out-of-memory issue : In my case I was added the high resolution image for background of the constraint-layout or in the same page(.xml file) we used the high resolution image for any imageview source.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues. For me, the reason is my project "**Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidXhas**". What to do? simply following two steps:

1st step:
Please check your **gradle.properties**, if you see the following lines, you might have the exact same issues as mine. You can firstly delete them.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

2nd step: in main activity, I changed

```
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
```

into

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
```

Everything works all of sudden!

Comment: support packages are depreacted and android recommends to use androidx

Answer (score 1):

please use ConstraintLayout dependency version '2.0.0-beta5', it has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the app run correctly in other phones but got this exception with a ZTE device. I fixed it by disabling Instant Run in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

add to your app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    ...
}
```