# App Crashes Instantly In Android Below Lollipop

Tags: android

I am Facing issues With My Android App The problem is its working fine above Lollipop. But Below Lollipop app crashes after launching the activity.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.latestkinnaurisongs.kinnaurigeet, PID: 2274
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.latestkinnaurisongs.kinnaurigeet/com.latestkinnaurisongs.kinnaurigeet.SignIn}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                    at com.latestkinnaurisongs.kinnaurigeet.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:46)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.latestkinnaurisongs.kinnaurigeet.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:46) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020054 a=-1 r=0x7f020054}
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2073)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
                                                                                    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:419)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:595) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                    at com.latestkinnaurisongs.kinnaurigeet.SignIn.onCreate(SignIn.java:46) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Its my logcat of Error
Can anyone please tell me whats Wrong With it and why this kind of behaviour in App.

Although it works On devices Above Lollipop But below that it crashes.
What is the reason of crash ??

res hierarchy

[image: click here]

Here is my `AndroidManifest` contains

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And `activity_start.xml` contains

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/googleBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.898"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>
```

Its in a `ConstraintLayout`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/app_star3"
tools:context="com.latestkinnaurisongs.kinnaurigeet.SignIn"></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: do one thing , select `project` view instead of android and post pic of your complete `res` hierarchy , it usually happens when you don't have layout or resoirce under required directory

Comment: Can you post the XML of the layout of the activity?

Comment: But 5.0 and above its working

Comment: @Kevinrob Added Layout Activity.

Comment: Check the app_star3 drawable XML. You are probably referencing a drawable attribute in XML  where a drawable resource is expected. Theme attributes inside drawable XML is only supported since API 21

Comment: Yes!! wait checking if removing this can solve the error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using **ConstraintLayout** in your project, please check

[Error inflating class ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42501868/error-inflating-class-constraintlayout)

I hope it will help....

Comment: I have added My ConstraintLayout  can you tell where it is causing error.

Comment: Can you add StartActivity.java file