# Android Studio 3.1.3 having issues with Constraint layout, Error Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Tags: android-studio

This is the issue i am getting.

[image]

Error not rendering issue

i tried all the options available on the web. it is a new installation of studio 3.1.3 and it is happening for every new project as i did not test with any old project as i do not have one.

steps to recreate is to clean installation of android studio 3.1.3 and create a new project. i tried to create multiple projects but same issue.

i tried all the options available on [Android Studio 3.1.3 having issues with Constraint layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50868924/android-studio-3-1-3-having-issues-with-constraint-layout) link but all are failing.

any one let me a studio version name where i will not get this issue. i just wanted to develop a app. and i am not a andriod developer. so these issues are very annoying for me.

Answer (score 4):

Have the same problem. I think it's from Android SDK Platform 28 so I uninstall it, and use Android SDK Platform 27 and it work for me.

To uninstall : Tools> SDK Manager> System setting> Android SDK> Show package detail(little
                box on the right below corner)> Put out the check sign from Android SDK 
                Platform 28 > apply and try new project.

Note : Sorry for bad English.