# Gradle mixing versions 28.0.0-beta01 and 26.1.0

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, version

I got the problem that Android Studio constantly says that I am mixing 28.0.0-beta01 and 26.1.0 but I don't use a library with 26.1

I checked out some other posts but either there is no explanation or one that I didn't got to work.

Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "at.mrminemeet.asciimoji"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 31
        versionName '2.1'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: can you share your gradle dependecy tree?
`gradle app:dependencies`

Answer (score 2):

Using `gradle app:dependencies` to check the dependencies. BAsed on the result, you can fix the problem easily

Comment: Yes. Line no. 128 says +--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0@aar. Hence you need to check from which library you are getting this wrong dependency

Comment: Problem is with constraintlayout. It is still not compatible with 28. it works with 27.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940882/2610808 You can try to use the latest alpha version and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have used different versions of the support library. All supported library versions must be the same