# Making View in XML

Tags: android, xml

[image]

Just on a lighter note, can u guys give me a hint how to make a view like this. I m not asking to write code for me. I just need few suggestions. When click on bottom right corner a new screen shows which has transparent background where a little bit main activity is visible and contents are not aligned vertical or horizontal.
Your ideas would be appreciated

Comment: ConstraintLayout can easily solve the need.

Comment: ok let me try for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full screen dialog with Constraint Layout or Relative Layout

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: how can i make full screen dialog

Comment: set the dialog theme to one of the fullscreen theme `android.R.style.Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: there is a problem while using constraint layout it gives me this error `Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.Guideline`

Comment: [Please refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42502151/5403852)

Comment: One more question as u can see the background of dialog is not transparent.. can u tell me which color is this?

Comment: The color will be something like this `#8BFF0000`,  add this color as background to your constraint layout

Comment: there is a problem now when i use the content of activity its backend of activity is  not working means if i have button in my activity then on click of button is not working